# how to send react-native-audio-record recorded audio file to server?

Tags: laravel, file-upload, react-native, file-get-contents

I need to be record audio and upload audio to server and for the record audio i am using "**react-native-audio-record**" react native package.

When i am using `file_get_contents($request->file('inputFile'))` all time `file_get_contents returning 500 internal server error` to me in **Laravel**.

I tried **form-data**, **blob object**.

Here is my React Native code and everything what i used to solve this:

```
onStartRecord = async () => {
    this.setState({ isPlaying: false })
    let dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      try {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
          {
            title: 'Permissions for write access',
            message: 'Give permission to your storage to write a file',
            buttonPositive: 'ok',
          },
        );
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
          console.log('You can use the storage');
        } else {
          console.log('permission denied');
          return;
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
        return;
      }
    }
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      try {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.RECORD_AUDIO,
          {
            title: 'Permissions for write access',
            message: 'Give permission to your storage to write a file',
            buttonPositive: 'ok',
          },
        );
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
          console.log('You can use the camera');
        } else {
          console.log('permission denied');
          return;
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
        return;
      }
    }
    const path = Platform.select({
      ios: 'hello.m4a',
      //android: dirs.DocumentDir+'/hello.aac',
      android: 'sdcard/hello.mp3',
    });
    const audioSet: AudioSet = {
      // AudioEncoderAndroid: AudioEncoderAndroidType.AAC,
      // AudioSourceAndroid: AudioSourceAndroidType.MIC,
      // AVEncoderAudioQualityKeyIOS: AVEncoderAudioQualityIOSType.high,
      // AVNumberOfChannelsKeyIOS: 2,
      // AVFormatIDKeyIOS: AVEncodingOption.aac,
    };
    //console.log('audioSet', audioSet);
    const uri = await this.audioRecorderPlayer.startRecorder(path);
    console.log("URI => ",uri);


    // RNFS.readFile(uri, 'base64')
    // .then(res =>{
    //   console.log(res);
    // });
    // RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile(path, base64Str, 'base64');
    // RNFetchBlob.android.actionViewIntent(path, 'application/aac');

    this.audioRecorderPlayer.addRecordBackListener((e: any) => {
      //console.log("E ====>>>>>>>>>",e);
      this.setState({
        recordSecs: e.current_position,
        recordTime: this.audioRecorderPlayer.mmssss(
          Math.floor(e.current_position),
        ),
      });
    });
    //alert(`uri: ${uri}`);
    // var body = new FormData();
    // //console.log("BODY",abc);
    // body.append('file', uri);
    //
    // console.log("+++++++=========body=========++++++",body);

    var body = new FormData();
    //console.log("BODY",abc);
    body.append('inputFile', {
       name: 'sound.mp4',
       type: 'audio/mp3',
       uri: uri
    });
    console.log("+++++++=========body=========++++++",body);
    // console.log("BODY",body);
    // RNFS.readFile(uri, "base64").then(data => {
    //   // binary data
    //   console.log("+++++++=========URI=========++++++",data);
    // });





      // const formData = [];
      // formData.push({
      //   name: "sound",
      //   filename: `sound.mp4`,
      //   data: RNFetchBlob.wrap(uri)
      // });

    const blob = await (await fetch(uri)).blob();
    // const file = new File(this.state.recordTime, `me-at-thevoice${1}.mp3`, {
    //     type: blob.type,
    //     lastModified: Date.now()
    // });
    // console.log("Bolb data file",file);

    var bodyData = new FormData();
    //console.log("BODY",abc);
    bodyData.append('inputFile', { blob });
    //
    // console.log("RNFetchBlob blob",blob);
    // await new Promise(resolve => {
    //  var reader = new FileReader();
    //  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    //  reader.onloadend = () => {
    //      var base64data = reader.result;
    //     console.log("reader",reader);
    //     console.log("base64data =--->>>",base64data);
    //      // let pth = path
    //      // RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile(pth, reader.result.substr(base64data.indexOf(',')+1), 'base64').then((res) => {
    //     //   console.log("RNFetchBlob res",res);
    //      //  blob.close()
    //      //  resolve();
    //      // });
    //
        this.props.setLoader(true);
        this.props.uploadAudio(bodyData).then(result => {
          console.log("this.props.audioRecordingResponse |||||=====|||||",this.props.audioRecordingResponse);
          if (this.props.audioRecordingResponse.success) {
             this.handler('success','Success',this.props.audioRecordingResponse.message);
             // this.refs["sign"].resetImage();
             // this.setState({
             //   signatures: [],
             //   isDragged: false,
             //   signatureCount: 0
             // })
             //this.props.navigation.navigate('AudioRecording',{templateId:templateId, documentId: documentId});

          } else {
            this.props.setLoader(false);
            this.handler('error','Error',this.props.audioRecordingResponse.message);
          }
        })

    //  }
    // })

  };
```

Please let me know if anyone having solution for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this answers your specific case, but this is how I send my code from a react native app:

```
import AudioRecord from 'react-native-audio-record';
import * as RNFS from 'react-native-fs'
.....
record = () => {
    if (!this.state.recording) {
        this.setState({recording: true}, () => {
            AudioRecord.start()
        })
    } else {
        AudioRecord.stop().then(r => {
            this.setState({recording: false})

            RNFS.readFile(r, 'base64') // r is the path to the .wav file on the phone
                .then((data) => {

                    this.context.socket.emit('sendingAudio', {
                        sound: data
                    });
                })
        });


    }
}
```

I use sockets for my implementation but you can use pretty much anything as all I am sending is a long string. On the server side I then decode the string as so:

```
export async function sendingAudio(data) {

  let fileName = `sound.wav`
  let buff = Buffer.from(data.sound, 'base64');
  await fs.writeFileSync(fileName, buff)
}
```

So basically I create a wav file on the phone, then read it into a base64 encoding, send that to the server and on the server I decode it from base64 into a .wav file.

For Laravel I believe this could help you [Decode base64 audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30572374/how-to-convert-base64-string-into-an-audio-mp3-file) . Just dont save it as mp3 but a wav.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i changed the package "react-native-audio-record".

Comment: It looks more pretty.