# How to store songs on MySQL database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am making a project where I can import music to my website using csv and xlsx file format and use table view to list the songs. I can’t find any good tutorial or source code for this.

Comment: Look for tutorials that save form data to a database and display the results in HTML. Then look for tutorials that read/parse csv/xlsx files into values. Take the concepts from each and create your own application based on the knowledge. As for storing LOB data (the music file - mp3, wav, etc), I strongly suggest not using a RDBMS to store them. Instead save the file path reference to where the file is located on the disk in the database.

Comment: I STRONGLY discourage using RDBMS to store files. But there is a way. You can `base64` encoding to convert the file to text and save. Refer:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30572374/how-to-convert-base64-string-into-an-audio-mp3-file
But the best way is to save the files in the server and store the path in the database.